# How to make MudBlazor MudDataGrid horizontal scroll available without having to vertical scroll to bottom of the MudDataGrid displayed rows first?

Tags: html, datagrid, blazor, scrollbar, mudblazor

In the MudBlazor MudDataGrid, the horizontal scroll is unavailable unless the vertical scroll is used to scroll to the bottom of the displayed rows in the MudDataGrid. Then once the horizontal scroll is available, the user must scroll to the right to expose the needed columns, but then the user needs to vertical scroll back up to the rows they needed to view to begin with.

How do I make the MudBlazor MudDataGrid horizontal scroll available all the time?

```
<MudDataGrid T="Repair"
             Items="@Page.Repairs"
             Sortable="true" SortMode="SortMode.Multiple" ColumnResizeMode="ResizeMode.Column"
             Filterable="false"
             Outlined="true"
             Loading="Page.ProcessingSubmitQuery"
             RowsPerPage="10"
             Hover="true"
             QuickFilter="@QuickFilter">
    <ToolBarContent>
        <MudText Typo="Typo.body1" Class="mr-1">Job Number:</MudText><MudText Typo="Typo.h6" Class="mr-4">@Page.JobNumber</MudText>
        <MudText Typo="Typo.body1" Class="mr-1">Repair Code:</MudText><MudText Typo="Typo.h6" Class="mr-4">@Page.RepairCode</MudText>
        <MudText Typo="Typo.body1" Class="mr-1">Customer Id:</MudText><MudText Typo="Typo.h6" Class="mr-8">@Page.CustomerId</MudText>
        @*<MudTextField @bind-Value="searchString" Placeholder="Search" Adornment="Adornment.Start" Immediate="true" AdornmentIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Search" IconSize="Size.Medium" Class="mt-0" />*@
        <MudSpacer />
        <MudButton Class="ml-4" @onclick="ExportToExcelAsync" Color="Color.Primary" Variant="Variant.Outlined">Export to Excel</MudButton>
    </ToolBarContent>
    <Columns>
        <Column T="Repair" Field="Repair_Id" Sortable="true" Title="#" CellStyle="width: 10px" h>
            <CellTemplate>
                <MudLink Href="@GetRepairDetailPageLink(context.Repair_Id)" Target="_blank">
                    <MudText Style="color:darkblue">@context.Repair_ID</MudText>
                </MudLink>
            </CellTemplate>
        </Column>
        <Column T="Repair" Field="Mechanic" Sortable="true" Title="Mechanic" CellStyle="min-width: 10px" />
        <Column T="Repair" Field="Description" Sortable="false" Title="Description" CellStyle="min-width: 300px" />
        <Column T="Repair" Field="Repair" Sortable="false" Title="Repair Made" CellStyle="min-width: 200px" />       
    </Columns>
    <PagerContent>
        <MudDataGridPager T="Repair" PageSizeOptions=@(new int[] {10, 25, 50, 100, 150, 200 }) />
    </PagerContent>
</MudDataGrid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to solve this by setting HorizontalScrollbar to true and adding css to your datagrid:

```
<MudDataGrid T="Repair" Items="@repairs" Sortable="true" SortMode="SortMode.Multiple" ColumnResizeMode="ResizeMode.Column" Filterable="false" Outlined="true"
             RowsPerPage="10" Hover="true" HorizontalScrollbar="true" Style="max-height: 500px; max-width: 600px; overflow: scroll;">
    <ToolBarContent>
        <MudText Typo="Typo.body1" Class="mr-1">Job Number:</MudText><MudText Typo="Typo.h6" Class="mr-4">job #</MudText>
        <MudText Typo="Typo.body1" Class="mr-1">Repair Code:</MudText><MudText Typo="Typo.h6" Class="mr-4">repair code</MudText>
        <MudText Typo="Typo.body1" Class="mr-1">Customer Id:</MudText><MudText Typo="Typo.h6" Class="mr-8">customer id</MudText>
        <MudSpacer />
        <MudButton Class="ml-4" @onclick="ExportToExcelAsync" Color="Color.Primary" Variant="Variant.Outlined">Export to Excel</MudButton>
    </ToolBarContent>
    <Columns>
        <Column T="Repair" Field="Repair_Id" Sortable="true" Title="#" CellStyle="width: 10px" h>
            <CellTemplate>
                <MudLink Href="#" Target="_blank">
                    <MudText Style="color: darkblue">@context.Item.Repair_Id</MudText>
                </MudLink>
            </CellTemplate>
        </Column>
        <Column T="Repair" Field="Mechanic" Sortable="true" Title="Mechanic" CellStyle="min-width: 10px" />
        <Column T="Repair" Field="Description" Sortable="false" Title="Description" CellStyle="min-width: 300px" />
        <Column T="Repair" Field="RepairsMade" Sortable="false" Title="Repair Made" CellStyle="min-width: 200px" />
    </Columns>
    <PagerContent>
        <MudDataGridPager T="Repair" PageSizeOptions=@(new int[] {10, 25, 50, 100, 150, 200 }) />
    </PagerContent>
</MudDataGrid>
```

You can check out this MudBlazor snippet to see it working (just click the play button in the top left to load it): https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/cYQHYGGHCGuEaJEO

Comment: Unfortunately, setting ` HorizontalScrollbar="true"` does not seem to change the behavior of the horizontal scrollbar. The horizontal scroll bar was already present and is not available until I vertical scroll do the bottom of the displayed rows of the MudDataGrid even with ` HorizontalScrollbar="true" enabled.

Comment: @TysonGibby could you provide a code sample in your post?

Comment: Thanks, for helping me with this. Code example has been added.

Comment: @TysonGibby I updated my answer to look more like your code, and provided a snippet you can check out. However, its still using the same solution as before. If its still not working could there be a div or some other element that is effecting the size?

Comment: Your example is working well. Mine code still is not. One difference I am noticing is that your scroll bar generates after the PagerContent while mine generates just before it. I think it may be because of the version of MudBlazor. I am still on version 5.25. because I am on .NET 5 for this project. I will be upgrading to .NET 6 next week. I will try again then. Thank you.

Comment: Finally got the upgrade to VS 2022 on my machine and I have updated the project to .NET 6 and installed the latest MudBlazor. It is working like your example now. Thank you.

Comment: @TysonGibby yay! I'm glad you could finally get it working